# Should I use LIMIT when I'm using ORDER BY?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I read somewhere:

> You **must** use `LIMIT` clause when you're using `ORDER BY` clause. If you don't, you sometimes  will be surprisingly faced with different results.

Is that true?

---

Actually here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(score) score, type, context, post_id, other_id, MAX(date_time)
FROM `events` e
WHERE e.id IN ($ids)
GROUP BY type, post_id, other_id
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc, MAX(date_time) desc, MAX(e.id) desc
```

**Note:** `$ids` is a PHP variable contains a string like this: `1, 2, 4, 76`.

Should I use `LIMIT` in my query? If yes/not, then why?

Comment: You have that backwards. You may get inconsistent results when using `LIMIT` _without_ using `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Nicarus Oh right .. What you said is exactly what I read already somewhere `:-)` .. thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to limit the number of rows returned then don't use limit. If you do want to limit the number of rows returned then use limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would using an ORDER BY clause both increase and decrease performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016273/how-would-using-an-order-by-clause-both-increase-and-decrease-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to use `LIMIT` if you don't want to. *(I have no idea what the author meant by "surprisingly faced with different results ...")*

The `ORDER BY` clause, as you very well know, specifies that the result-set should be sorted.  Likewise, `LIMIT`, as you *also* very well know, specifies that you only want to see the first *n* rows of that result-set *(sorted or not)*.

The two clauses, then, are entirely independent of one another. If you want *all* of the *(sorted, or not)* rows that would be returned by the query, you are under no obligation to use `LIMIT`, and, in fact, ought not do so.

Comment: They're not really independent. LIMIT without ORDER BY is a fairly meaningless concept.

Comment: Though it might seem nonsensical (since SQL does not mandate that rows will be returned in any particular order if you don't *specify* the ordering that you want), "`LIMIT` by itself" is nevertheless perfectly valid. The slice-of-records that is returned will be based on the table's default order of occurrence, whatever that is.

Comment: Yes, but really there's no such thing as a default order.

Comment: Granted.  You will get *some* slice of records, nevertheless.